# what is the proper way of running for loop with scanf function

Tags: c, printf, scanf, c11

I just started learning c. I have a code here for taking input from users and printing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5];
    int i ;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
         printf("enter the %d position no: ",i+1);
         scanf("%d \n",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0;i<5;i++)
        printf("position %d : %d \n",i+1,a[i]);

}
```

Here is my output console.

[image]

But the output is giving misleading result.
at line 2 when scanf is reding it is not showing the string "enter the %d position" it is directly asking for value.

Comment: lose the \n in your scanf. Read about the [effects of trailing white space in scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Comment: use cout and cin it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `scanf` doesn't need the space and the newline character, just `"%d"`.

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
     printf("enter the %d position no: ",i+1);
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Not checking the return value in a loop...

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix to your problem: `scanf("%d \n",&a[i])` -> `scanf("%d",&a[i])`

Also, remember to always check `scanf` for errors. It can be done like this:

```
if(scanf("%d", &a[i]) < 0) {
    // Print error message and/or exit or whatever you want to do
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

In the long run:

Take some time studying input methods in C. They are a bit tricky and there are millions of pitfalls. In short, `scanf` is a good choice *provided* that the input is in the exact format that you expect. This makes it a bad choice for user input, because users are quite unpredictable.

Here is a link worth reading:

http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/02/07/scanf-and-why-you-should-avoid-using-it/

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   printf("enter the %d position on : ",i+1);
   scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   printf("\n");
}
```